# How to access a ListViewItem's property which is in a DataTemplate through code?

Tags: c++, xaml, listview, uwp, windows-runtime

I have a xaml file in which I have a ListView (let's call it OuterListView) which I can access by name. OuterListView's ItemTemplate uses a a StaticResource, let's call it a CustomListViewItem. CustomListViewItem is defined in the same file as a DataTemplate and it also has a ListView (let's call it InnerListView), which also uses CustomListViewItem as an ItemTemplate.

So it looks like this:

```
 OuterListView (CustomListViewItems as its Items)
     CustomListViewItem (each of the below 3 may have its own ListView (InnerListView) as defined in DataTemplate)
     CustomListViewItem
     CustomListViewItem
```

The thing I'm trying to achieve is to select all the Items from the InnerListViews by clicking a "Select All" button. I'm clicking it and I can iterate through the CustomListViewItems, easy because I have the name of the OuterListViews but unfortunately I don't know how to access the elements from the CustomListViewItems' InnerListViews in order to set the IsSelected property via C++ code.

If you have any tips how to do that or if you know for sure it's impossible (unlikely) - please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide your xaml code to help us further check the problem for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VisualTreeHelper Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper?view=winrt-22621) to access the elements from the CustomListViewItems' InnerListViews.

First use `GetParent` to get the root node(OuterListView), then start looking for child controls from the root node, which can be searched according to the control type or x:name.

```
private void InnerListViewSelectAllItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var customListView = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
    var outerListView  = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(customListView);

    List<InnerListViews> results= null;
    FindChildren(results, outerListView);

    for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
    {
        results[i].SelectAll();
    }
}
       
internal static void FindChildren<T>(List<T> results, DependencyObject startNode)
where T : DependencyObject
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(startNode);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject current = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(startNode, i);
        if ((current.GetType()).Equals(typeof(T)) || (current.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))))
        {
            T asType = (T)current;
            results.Add(asType);
        }
        FindChildren<T>(results, current);
    }
}
```

---

```
public static DependencyObject MyFindChildByName(DependencyObject parant, string ControlName)
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
        if (MyChild is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)MyChild).Name == ControlName)
            return MyChild;

        var FindResult = MyFindChildByName(MyChild, ControlName);
        if (FindResult != null)
            return FindResult;
    }

    return null;
}
```

C++ code sample: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/Logging/cpp/Scenario2.xaml.cpp#L34